# Software that will tell me my CPU's temperature?

Tags: cpu, temperature

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good software for measuring computer temperature?](https://superuser.com/questions/2119/good-software-for-measuring-computer-temperature)

Hi,

What should my i7 920 temperate be under normal load?

I have a gigabyte ex58 ud4p mb.

Comment: Your question doesn't really match your subject

Comment: You should mention your OS. There is different software to do that on different OSes

Comment: Agree with above comments. Also, if it is Windows, the question in the subject has already been answered here: http://superuser.com/questions/2119/good-software-for-measuring-computer-temperature

Answer (score 9):

http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php

If your motherboard does not have many options or software to view the information you want, speedfan is a great alternative that will find any sensors your computer may have.

Answer (score 2):

Your BIOS will usually tell you your CPU's temperature. Additional software like [CoreTemp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) will also work although I'm unsure about it's accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) for a very long time to accomplish just this, because my computer fans are not too great. SpeedFan provides very many options and shows you all the core and ambient temperatures that are measurable for your computer. I really recommend it. The interface is also quite simple, and getting it up and running is easy!

By the way, SpeedFan also allows you to change clock options for your motherboard, as well as many other things. It has a very cool graphing option now, which you MUST check out! ;)

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OSX, [Temperature Monitor](http://www.bresink.de/osx/0TMonWidget/history.html) is a dashboard widget, by Marcel Bresink Software Systeme, the makers of Tinker Tool.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [realtemp](http://www.techpowerup.com/realtemp/), which is also completely portable.

Answer (score 0):

I've just started using Piriform Speccy which gives a whole bundle of extra data about your entire system. Freeware and a great tool.

Comment: if this is a windows tool, consider posting this answer on the duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/2119/good-software-for-measuring-computer-temperature ... also, links to the mfg's site are encouraged.  :)

Answer (score 0):

[Core Temp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/): Fast, free, and accurate.  It comes in 32-bit and 64-bit builds.  I use it on both my servers to monitor temperatures.  You can also have it log temperatures so you can graph out trends in a spreadsheet.