# Utility for monitoring fan speed etc

Tags: windows-xp, software-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good software for measuring computer temperature?](https://superuser.com/questions/2119/good-software-for-measuring-computer-temperature)

Can anyone recommend me a good, free utility for monitoring the computer, cpu temperature and fan speeds etc?

Comment: I am convinced this is a duplciate. Someone please confirm.

Comment: This one? http://superuser.com/questions/2119/good-software-for-measuring-computer-temperature

Comment: @joe Nope, that was different. For him SpeedFan wasn't working. @hyperslug that was the one :)

Comment: @alex : i have deleted my comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***For Windows***

[SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) is a program that monitors voltages, fan speeds and temperatures  in computers with hardware monitor chips.

Answer (score 3):

**[HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/hwmonitor.php)** is great to monitor voltage and temperatures. And it's free as well!

[image]

*While you're there, check also their other applications. [PC Wizard](http://www.cpuid.com/pcwizard.php) is great too and a free alternative to Lavalys Everest or Sisoft Sandra.*