# Which software to log voltage readings?

Tags: windows, logging, voltage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good tool to monitor my computer’s sensors?](https://superuser.com/questions/150828/what-is-a-good-tool-to-monitor-my-computers-sensors)
>   [Utility for monitoring fan speed etc](https://superuser.com/questions/55203/utility-for-monitoring-fan-speed-etc/55206#55206)

I need to test my windows system when playing 3D intensive games and would like to record the voltage  readings on my ASUS motherboard. The most important point is that the program saves the readings to file as I'm diagnosing computer freezes so I need that the readings remain after an hard reset.

Comment: I asked for a program that LOGS (i.e. periodically writes to file) the reading, because I need to test the system while playing full screen games.

Comment: I agree, they used a false reason to close your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Speedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) would be a good choice.

Comment: Does this program have logging capabilities? For what I know, it only monitors the sensor readings

Comment: It supports loggig. First you have to enable it from Configure->Log. You will find checkbox 'Logged' in the lower left of other tabs. The log will be saved in the program's directory.

Comment: Does not include the voltages in the most general cases