# Windows 7 PC powering off with no warning

Tags: hardware-failure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my computer power off suddenly and without warning?](https://superuser.com/questions/190620/why-does-my-computer-power-off-suddenly-and-without-warning)

I am stumped, and have tried everything I can think of to resolve this issue.

The machine (a Windows 7 PC) will power off without warning and at different intervals (sometimes it will shutdown after less than a minute of running and other times will run for over a week). And starts back up immediately after powering off.  The powering off is like all power is getting cut, I have even changed outlets to make sure its not the outlet).

I have run Disk Diags, both Windows 7 Disk Utility and fsck from a live Fedora image. No Errors
Ran CPU utility with logging to determine overheating issues.  No Errors or issues with temp
Run memory tests (no issues, so far.  I ran memtester under Linux with no errors but I am currently rerunning the Windows 7 Memory Utility). Memory is my current focus, I think one of the memory slots might be bad, but I am grasping at straws here.

I have replaced the Power Supply with the same issue presenting itself.
I have replaced the Case (just in case there was an issue with the shut off switch on the old case), and the same problem.

The MB is new and it ran fine for a while after I replaced it. This computer was given to me because it had fried the original MB due to an overheating issue.

Performance is fine when it is running. And I have not seen any errors in the event log nor any DrWatson logs.

The machine is now a home built (was an Acer)
Gigabyte MB
4 gigs of RAM (original from Acer)
Intel Duo Core CPU
SATA 500 gig HDD.

I am looking for suggestions on what the problem might be and tools (preferably free) that will help be diagnosis the problem.

My next step is to replace the Memory, CPU and MB, pretty making this a whole new machine.
I did have it shutdown on me under linux (this is off a live image on a USB Drive) so I don't think it is a Windows issue.

Power in the house is fine, I have other machines running without issue.

Once again even if you don't have a solution, a suggestion for a new direction to look or tools is appreciated.

Thanks everyone
Bill

Comment: Have you monitored the temp of the CPU for spikes around shutdown? Is the HSF adequate and properly installed? Have you replaced the thermal paste on it to ensure proper and even contact? Does it happen when you do something specific? Perhaps CPU intensive?

Comment: PC behaving like this, first reminds me of power issues. But if PSU and external power supply is fine, then the second option would be over-heating of the CPU. It's either of these two. Highly doubt it would be an MB issue, but that's kind of last resort.

Comment: [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/190620/why-does-my-computer-power-off-suddenly-and-without-warning) will help.

Comment: Raystafarian, I have monitored the CPU with speedfan and it shows no jumps in temps. And it starts up immediately after shutting down.  Which suggests to me that nothing needs to cool down.  And as far as specific actions prior to powering off, None.  Though I think I might redo the thermal paste.
Bibhas, I had read the question you posted prior to posting. And had tried several of the suggestions. But the other person had the one different symptom and that was the fact that it wouldn't power back up immediately. That is why I am not thinking it is overheating.