# CPU fan speed control

Tags: cpu, speedfan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good software for measuring computer temperature?](https://superuser.com/questions/2119/good-software-for-measuring-computer-temperature)

Hi,
Looking for a software that can control (set) the CPU fan speed at windows startup, currently I use CPUID but it does not have a feature to load my setting at windows startup.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

speedfan? http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php