# How do I check my temps inside my case?

Tags: temperature

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good software for measuring computer temperature?](https://superuser.com/questions/2119/good-software-for-measuring-computer-temperature)

Do I need to buy anything special to know the temps on my CPU and video card?

Answer (score 2):

There is quite a lot of programs that can give you this information, a few of the popular ones are

- [Speedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) To check all sensors
- [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) To check video card specific information

Comment: I don't need to buy any sensors?

Comment: no in modern hardware there's built in sensors in your cpu, gpu, motherboard, hard drives and possibly more