# How do I check CPU temperature in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, cpu, temperature

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I measure my computer temperature?](https://superuser.com/questions/2119/how-can-i-measure-my-computer-temperature)

On my previous PC I have used some gadgets to measure the temperature.

How can I measure it on Windows 8?

Comment: My motherboard manufacturer (ASUS) makes software that does that and runs on Windows 8.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/2119/how-can-i-measure-my-computer-temperature. Most of these should still work on Windows 8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use [Speccy](http://speccy.com/) by Piriform. It does more than just CPU temp.

Answer (score 18):

I use [OpenHardwareMonitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/) which adds a Gadget you can customize

[image]

Comment: What program did you use to capture the screenshot with the shadow behind them? I see them everywhere, but I can never find a program that does.

Comment: this is the screenshot from their homepage and it looks like this is Windows 7.

Comment: I know it's Windows 7. I'm just wondering what program saves the shadow with the screenshot.

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson Something like [WinSnap](http://www.ntwind.com/software/winsnap.html)

Answer (score 2):

I have always used third party software to monitor temperatures. See if this work in Windows 8 on desktop mode: [CoreTemp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/)

Comment: Yep - this works in windows 8. It also works a bit like a gadget in that it will silently stay in the background when minimized and pop up an alert when the temp reaches a critical point.

Comment: It also installs 'Search Protect' malware that hijacks web browsers. Don't go anywhere near it.