# Windows 8 Infinite reboot loop

Tags: windows-8, reboot

I've installed windows 8 just now and after I install drivers it gets stuck in an infinite reboot loop.

I'm thinking it has something to do with the chipset. The motherboard is an ASUS P8Z68-V.

I downloaded the correct drivers from the Asus website and I've also updated my BIOS to the latest version.

I had the problem when installing the chipset driver from the asus website. I skipped this one after a reinstall and then installed the rest. Seems like that wasn't the problem.

I read around but couldn't get any decent answers. I tried a memtest86+ and that came back negative. Next i tried to set the SATA settings in BIOS to AHCI/RAID/IDE, that didn't help either.

I'm kinda stuck here on what to do.

Specs:

Intel Core I5 2500K
OCZ Vertex 3 60GB
6 GB Kingston DDR3 PC10600
ASus P8Z68-V
2 other regular SATA hdd's

Comment: If possible place your minidump to free file hosting. Then we can figure out something specific.http://forums.techguy.org/attachments/216265d1351440948t/untitled2.png

Comment: I tried doing as you told me but I didn't manage to get windows to create a minidump. He only does that with a BSOD?

Comment: How can I measure my computer temperature http://superuser.com/questions/2119/how-can-i-measure-my-computer-temperature Enable boot logging in windows 8 http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/6cde20/enable-boot-logging-in-windows-8/

Comment: Okay, So I've got a bootlog, and here it is. I can't make much up out of it, so i'm relying on you guys. Thanks a lot!! :) http://begijnhof.no-ip.org:8080/Shared/Overige/ntbtlog.txt

Comment: I just did a refresh, since I've tried an older version of the bios and this is what the list of removed apps is: http://begijnhof.no-ip.org:8080/Shared/Overige/Removed%20Apps.html

Comment: Okay, So i got into the system by using the refresh option. When I installed http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&ProdId=816&DwnldID=20775&ProductFamily=Software+Products&ProductLine=Chipset+Software&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+Chipset+Software+Installation+Utility&lang=eng this tool. So I guess this is the problme. Is my motherboard just not compatible with windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

ntbtlog.txt:

```
@hal.inf,%acpi_amd64.devicedesc%;ACPI x64-based PC BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED
```

Need APCI hal reinstall.

Advanced Configuration and Power Interface - a term not accurately reflect its member technology and introduces a direct error.

ACPI is not only the manager of supply. ACPI - allocator and root device enumerator. ACPI - the root of the device tree.

Incorrectly ACPI - incorrectly can work all  device.

Need [Z68 chipset driver](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&keyword=Z68) but ia not all set.

Comment: Okay, so it worked, but now it's back. Frustrating as hell :( I installed  that chipset driver but that didn't work. So i hard copied the driver over the current one, but that didn't work either. I'm kinda stuck here now on what to do. It has worked fine for a couple of weeks, but now, suddenly..

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer Your BIOS version 3603(Only for Win7 & Win8) ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue that indicated similar to your issue that it might be chipset drivers.

The solution for me was to get a beta version of NVidia's drivers for Windows 8.1 and that solved the issue.

The bits are a little tricky to find for my specific machine setup (Lenovo W530, NVidia Quadro 1000M, running Windows 8.1 preview) but the version that solved my problem was 326.19.

http://www.nvidia.com/object/notebook-win8-win7-64bit-326.19-beta-driver.html

Hope that helps.